# Azure mobile log query

Tags: azure, command-line, command-line-interface, azure-mobile-services

Azure has very useful command line tools, which, among others, can retrieve logs from Mobile service. like this:

```
azure mobile log SERVICE_NAME
```

This command has `--query` option where you can pass "log query".

I doubt this feature might be very useful, but could not find any additional info about it. Help output says only `log query; takes precedence over --type, --continuationToken, and --top`. There's not much more written in online documentation.

Please tell, what can be done with this option and what is the syntax of this "log query"?
Any links where I can get more info would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to this question by looking at the source code for the command-line tools (https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools-xplat/blob/master/lib/commands/mobile.js, lines 1574-1621 and 258-288). The three parameters (--top, --continuationToken, --type) are translated into query string parameters, which is sent to the service. The --top maps directly to the `$top` parameter, --continuationToken maps directly to `continuationToken`, and --type maps to the `$filter` parameter, with a predicate about the 'type' field.

For example, this command (line-feeds added for clarity)

```
azure mobile log SERVICE_NAME --top 5
                              --continuationToken <the cont token>
                              --type information
```

Is the same as  (line-feeds added for clarity)

```
azure mobile log SERVICE_NAME --query "$top=5&
                                       continuationToken=<the cont token>&
                                       $filter=type eq 'information'"
```

The query capabilities are quite limited, but you can do things like `type ne 'information'` (not equal to), or `Source eq '/table/mytablename.insert.js'` (querying for things other than type).

Comment: Thanks @carlosfigueira. Sorry I could not come back to this question for some time. This seems to work, but I still could not made what I need. `azure mobile log SERVICE_NAME --query '$top=3&continuationToken=2520316853846039999-3066e04f-b0e2-4798-8061-b1e1822bfeb7'` does work as expected, but `azure mobile log SERVICE_NAME --query '$top=3&$filter=type eq '"'information'"` gives `There are no matching log entries` when there should be some. (I am using slightly different quoting, cause I am doing it from mac and "$top" tries to give the environment variable value).

Comment: I have tied some different variations like: `azure mobile log SERVICE_NAME --query '$top=3&$filter=type eq "information"'` and `azure mobile log SERVICE_NAME --query '$top=3&$filter=type eq information'` but this time I get `The server encountered an internal error. Please retry the request`.

Comment: Actually my goal is to filter by source files (cause all other I can do with command line options). I try following: `azure mobile log SERVICE_NAME --query '$top=3&$filter=source eq '"'/scheduler/executeBackgroundJobs.js'"` and again get `There are no matching log entries`.

Comment: Try querying for `Source` (with capital 'S'), and it should work - when I queried for `source eq '/scheduler/myJob.js'` it didn't return anything, but by querying for `Source eq '/scheduler/myJob.js'` I got some results. I also updated my answer with the corrected name.

Comment: Yes it worked! and with `Type` (with capital 'T') as well. Thank you very much.